# mysql display data based on date range from database using inner join

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have two table events and session which looks like this

Events table

[image]

Sessions table[image]

I want to display data based on date ranges

Here is my solution

```
SELECT sessions.sid, events.datetime, count(*) as num_rows, 
  count(distinct sessions.sid) as sessions, 
  sum( targetbuttonname = 'kredyt' ) as num_kredyt, 
  sum( targetbuttonname = 'konto' ) as num_konto,
  sum( targetbuttonname = 'czat' ) as num_czat,
  sum( targetbuttonname = 'video-voice_btns' ) as num_voice,
  sum( targetbuttonname = 'video-close_btn' )  as num_close,
  sum( targetbuttonname = 'video-muted_btn' ) as num_muted,
  sum( targetbuttonname = 'video-play_btn' )  as num_play,
  sum( targetbuttonname = 'video-pause_btn' )  as num_pause,
  sum( targetbuttonname = 'video-replay_btn' ) as num_replay, 
  sum(watchtime) as num_watchtime, 
  sum(devicetype ='Computer') as num_computer from events 
  INNER JOIN sessions ON (events.sid =sessions.sid) 
  WHERE datetime BETWEEN '2019-11-11' AND '2019-11-21'
```

Unfortunately when i run the script on phpmyadmin I am getting the following error

## 1052 - Column: 'datetime' in where clause is ambiguous

What am I doing wrong in my code?

Here is jsfiddle [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3cf3cf/1)

Comment: So qualify it with the table name where it comes from.  In fact, **qualify** all your column references so it is clear where they come from -- both for the compiler and for people.

Comment: **datetime** is in both tables, just add the `table.column`. Eg: `sessions.datetime `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have "datetime" column in both of your tables. So when you are saying:

```
INNER JOIN sessions ON (events.sid = sessions.sid) 
WHERE datetime BETWEEN '2019-11-11' AND '2019-11-21'
```

it doesn't know which table your "datetime" is referring.

What you need to do is to refer the column from which table you are using like:

```
INNER JOIN sessions ON (events.sid = sessions.sid) 
WHERE sessions.datetime BETWEEN '2019-11-11' AND '2019-11-21'
```

Or like:

```
INNER JOIN sessions ON (events.sid = sessions.sid) 
WHERE events.datetime BETWEEN '2019-11-11' AND '2019-11-21'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use either `WHERE events.datetime BETWEEN '2019-11-11' AND '2019-11-21'` or `WHERE sessions.datetime BETWEEN '2019-11-11' AND '2019-11-21'` depending on the datetime you want to take into account.

A column with name `datetime` exists in both tables, so you have to qualify the column name.